# how to get 1 attribut from groupcollection?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

hi i have sample example with users and groups with a join manytomany .
but i dont know how to get attribute of my collectiongroup in Users my code is :

```
<p:dataTable var="user" value="#{usergestion.tableusers}" editable="true" > 

                            <p:column headerText="username" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{user.username}">  
                                <p:commandLink value="#{user.username}" action="#{usergestion.insertaaa()}"/>
                           </p:column>  

                           <p:column headerText="nom" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{user.nom}">  
                                <h:outputText value="#{user.nom}" />  
                           </p:column>  

                            <p:column headerText="groupe"> 
                            <h:outputText value="#{user.groupsCollection.get(0).groupname}"  />                           
                            </p:column>

                        </p:dataTable>
```

my `user.groupsCollection.get(0).groupname` isnt working well how i can show the group of my user ?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution :**

```
user.groupsCollection.toArray()[0].groupname
```

Comment: This solution shows a bad design. If you want/need to show only the first element of the array, then you should have it in a field in your entity class.

Comment: thats because of usinf manytomany join i need to use in place onetomany